# Please help me, I keep getting Error 1

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, realtek

When I install alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8 for from Realtek website. Since there is no sound and there is no other output device beside Digital output device. When I follow the instructions [image: here] but when I try to perform `sudo make` and `sudo make install` (Last steps) I keep getting this

make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQq4o.png): Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-26-generic'
      LEX     scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c
    /bin/sh: 1: flex: not found
    make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:9: scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c] Error 127
    make[2]:**  [Makefile:594: syncconfig] Error 2
    make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQq4o.png):  **[Makefile:704: include/config/auto.conf.cmd] Error 2
    make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQq4o.png): Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-26-generic'
    make: *** [Makefile:167: compile] Error 2

```
ronan@ronan-H110M-DS2:~/Downloads/0002-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa$ sudo make install
if [ -L /usr/include/sound ]; then \
    rm -f /usr/include/sound; \
    ln -sf /home/ronan/Downloads/0002-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/include/sound /usr/include/sound; \
else \
    rm -rf /usr/include/sound; \
    install -d -m 755 -g root -o root /usr/include/sound; \
    for f in include/sound/*.h; do \
        install -m 644 -g root -o root $f /usr/include/sound; \
    done \
fi
find /lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic/kernel/sound -name 'snd*.*o' | xargs rm -f
find /lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic/kernel/sound -name 'snd*.*o.gz' | xargs rm -f
find /lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic/kernel/sound -name 'ac97_bus.*o' | xargs rm -f
find /lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic/kernel/sound -name 'ac97_bus.*o.gz' | xargs rm -f
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ronan/Downloads/0002-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/include'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'modules_install'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ronan/Downloads/0002-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/include'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ronan/Downloads/0002-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore'
mkdir -p /lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic/kernel/sound/acore
cp snd-hrtimer.ko snd-hwdep.ko snd-page-alloc.ko snd-pcm.ko snd-rawmidi.ko snd-timer.ko snd.ko /lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic/kernel/sound/acore
cp: cannot stat 'snd-hrtimer.ko': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'snd-hwdep.ko': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'snd-page-alloc.ko': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'snd-pcm.ko': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'snd-rawmidi.ko': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'snd-timer.ko': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'snd.ko': No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [/home/ronan/Downloads/0002-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/Rules.make:49: modules_install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ronan/Downloads/0002-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore'
make: *** [Makefile:210: install-modules] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't compilea driver if you're a beginer. That's very hard.